# Rails - How to send confirmation code via SMS using nexmo api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vonage

We are creating a Rails application for implement the Nexmo API. In registration process, we need to send confirmation code through SMS to the user from server-side using Nexmo API.
But we don't have any idea about this. We wanted to implement this feature for India only.

I have used https://github.com/dotpromo/nexmos gem and my code is:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'nexmos'


#sms_controller.rb:

class SmsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @sms = Sms.new
  end
  def createclient = ::Nexmos::Message.new('#', '#')
    res = client.send_text(from: '+910000000000', to: '+910000000000', text: 'Hello world!') 
    if res.success?
      puts "ok"
    else
      puts "fail"
    end
  end 
end
```

I have used my credentials for "key" and "Secret" in-place of "#" and replace from and to with my phone numbers. but it doesn't works. Even after not delivering the SMS to other numbers, the success block is being executed.

Can anybody guide us to implement this?.

Comment: Show what you have done already, what kind of trouble you had and what's the expected result. This looks like you're trying to get consultancy on how do build something out of nothing and that's not the purpose of this website.

Comment: Define: "it doesn't work" : Do you get an error? Or: you do not get an error, but the sms is not delivered? Are the `<br>` copy-paste error, or is that actually in your code?

Comment: @nathanvda - i don't get any error but i can delivered sms on my number only which i was entered in my Nexmo profile.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you'd want to use the [Ruby library built for Nexmo.](https://github.com/timcraft/nexmo)

Essentially what you'd do is put this sample code:

```
nexmo = Nexmo::Client.new('...API KEY...', '...API SECRET...')

response = nexmo.send_message({
  from: 'RUBY',
  to: '...NUMBER...',
  text: 'Hello world'
})

if response.success?
  puts "Sent message: #{response.message_id}"
elsif response.failure?
  raise response.error
end
```

..inside an action in your controller. Let's say it's your `TextsController`, and you put it under the create action. So in your `config/routes.rb`, put something like:

```
match "/sendtext" => "texts#create"
```

Then, you just hit `mydomain.com/sendtext` and the command should fire.

via varatis

Comment: I have used https://github.com/timcraft/nexmo. but sms is delivered to only my number. i just wanted to send sms all indian phone numbers.Thanks